# Angular x2js xml not defined

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs

I'm tryin to make [this example](http://motyar.blogspot.com.tr/2014/08/how-to-parse-xml-in-angular-js.html) to use xml as json data. But i ve some problem about these code.

```
courses  = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
console.log(courses.books.course);
$scope.todos =courses.books.course;
```

In the xml of example. There are books and course tag. But i didnt understand where is 'courses' come from.

I'm tryin to do same example with this xml example

```
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
 <DocumentElement xmlns="">
  <semt_kodlari diffgr:id="semt_kodlari1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
   <semt_adi>ALTIKAT</semt_adi>
  </semt_kodlari>
 </DocumentElement>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

And here is my HTML part:

```
X = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
console.log(X.DocumentElement.semt_kodlari);
$scope.todos = X.DocumentElement.semt_kodlari;
```

When i run this code i take the "Cannot read property 'semt_kodlari' of undefined" error. So can somebody tell me what is wrong in my code and What is the diffrence about course and course's' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are only missing one parent of your object. If you add `diffgram` to you `console.log` it should work as expected.

See the demo below or here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/567rbjk8/).

```js
        var todoApp = angular.module('todosApp', []);

        todoApp.factory('todoFactory', function ($http) {
            var factory = {};

            factory.getTodos = function () {
                return $http.get("http://cdn.rawgit.com/motyar/bcf1d2b36e8777fd77d6/raw/bfa8bc0d2d7990fdb910927815a40b572c0c1078/out.xml");
            }

            return factory;
        });
        todoApp.factory('getXMLDataFactory', function() {
            
            var x2js = new X2JS(),
                //xml ="<MyRoot><test>Success</test><test2><item>val1</item><item>val2</item></test2></MyRoot>";

                xml = '<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">'+
 '<DocumentElement xmlns="">'+
  '<semt_kodlari diffgr:id="semt_kodlari1" msdata:rowOrder="0">'+
   '<semt_adi>ALTIKAT</semt_adi>'+
  '</semt_kodlari>'+
 '</DocumentElement>'+
'</diffgr:diffgram>';
            console.log(xml, x2js);
            
            return {
                get: function() { 
                    return x2js.xml_str2json(xml);
               }
            };         
        });
        todoApp.controller('todosCtrl', function ($scope, todoFactory, getXMLDataFactory) {

            $scope.todos = [];
            //loadTodos();
            loadData();
            
            function loadTodos() {
                todoFactory.getTodos().success(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    courses = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
                    console.log(courses.books.course);
                    $scope.todos = courses.books.course;
                });
            }
            
            function loadData() {
                console.log('test');
                $scope.todos = getXMLDataFactory.get()
                    .diffgram.DocumentElement.semt_kodlari;
                console.log($scope.todos);
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="http://demos.amitavroy.com/learningci/assets/js/xml2json.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="todosApp" ng-controller="todosCtrl">
     <h2>Parsing XML data with AngularJS</h2>
    {{todos|json}}
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but when get xml file from http i get the same error :/

Comment: Not sure what you're doing wrong with-out seeing your code. In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/567rbjk8/3/) I did a request to a XML file with `$http`. I've also found out that `transformResponse` is pretty handy to transform the xml into json.

Comment: @SercanSelçuk define `$http` on your controller and check your import in main `index.html file` , `x2js` module files which is in your node_modules or bower_components. If not defined in index , then call these two files `<script src="node_modules/.../x2js/xml2json.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/.../x2js/xml2json.min.js"></script>`